# What happened to Odo's "cousin"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the episode *Vortex*, the alien Croden shows and later gives Odo a life form Dr. Bashir believed to be related to Odo's species with limited shapeshifting abilities of its own, but it's never shown or mentioned later in the series- does anybody have any idea where it went?

Comment: Croden gave the [shapeshifting locket](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shapeshifting_locket) to Odo at the end of the episode, and that's the last time it was shown or mentioned in the series, so we can only speculate as to what happened to the locket after that.

Comment: Other such lockets [show up in *Star Trek Online*](https://sto.fandom.com/wiki/Shapeshifting_Lockets) as tradeable items but it doesn't seem to give any more details about what they are and where they came from or make any mention of Odo's in particular.

Comment: Episode titles go in quotation marks, folks...

Comment: @HamSandwich:   Everyone has the power to make edits, pal...